# How to open a popup window and bind to the popup window close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm opening a popup as follows:

```
popup = window.open(url, "", "width=600,height=300,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no");
popup.focus();
```

What I want to do is refresh the opener when the popup closes. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "opener"? The page that calls the popup? Or a link?

Comment: right, opener being the parent window that called the popup

Comment: Refreshing the window that called the popup will result in the popup being called again, since you will essentially be reloading the page / url. Your other option is to encapsulate your popup in a self-executing function that appends a url variable to the url the first time, and checks for that url variable when called, before popping up the window.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it (place it within `<head>...</head>`):

```
<script>
window.onunload=function(){
  if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
};
</script>
```

Comment: The page that opens the popup has DOM access to the popup. The `popup` variable in your page can stand in as `window`, so you should be able to do `popup.onunload=function(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem if you can't place anything inside the popup. If you can't change the popup then you have limited choices. You can essentially set a session variable when the window first opens (in PHP or whatever your server language is), and have the page auto-refresh once it gains focus (assuming the popup gets focus on initial load). Have your server code detect the session variable, and if it's set, simply don't write the script to the head.